# How many webapplication can we have on sharepoint port 80

Tags: iis, alternate-access-mapping, port

How many web applications can we create on SharePoint port 80 and what is the procedure to be followed to create more than one.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use the different host headers to configure multiple web applications on port 80.

Read the complete guide here.
http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2012/10/setup-multiple-sharepoint-web.html